# MySQL stops when exporting data from a table with large data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

MySQL is stopping when I am exporting data from a table with large data.

> mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `sales_entry_details` at row: 132371

MySQL is stopping for another reason which I could not resolve. So I decided to export it then the above error is showing.

This table contains **372882** rows.

What might cause *MySQL* to **stop**??

Are there any **configs** to change?

***I got these from error logs:***

```
2019-11-19T11:42:19.074634Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2019-11-19T11:42:19.076626Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2019-11-19T11:42:19.144444Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2019-11-19T11:43:15.348723Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
2019-11-19T11:43:15.351602Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2019-11-19T11:43:15.355585Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File .\retech\sales_entry_details.ibd: 'Windows aio' returned OS error 123. Cannot continue operation
2019-11-19T11:43:15.359611Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
2019-11-19T11:43:18.994689Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-11-19T11:44:56.106058Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: 13 threads created by InnoDB had not exited at shutdown!
```

Comment: A similar question has been answered - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091734/getting-lost-connection-to-mysql-when-using-mysqldump-even-with-max-allowed-pack). See if this helps?

Comment: MySql didn't stop. You lost your connection, maybe because you have a timeout set

Comment: @nacho I checked in service and it appears MySQL has stopped!!!!

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';``  And how long did it run before timing out?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when mysql goes down, I usually find issues in either:

`tail /var/log/mysql/error.log`

or:

OOM issue (something like `Out of memory in UB : OOM killed process xxx (mysqld)` from `dmesg`).

In case of OOM issue, [recalculate](http://mysqlcalculator.com) memory and tune `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in my.cnf.

Comment: I have change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` but still same error, I have added some log reports

Comment: Error 23 is "file table overflow", meaning "mysql cannot open more files".

check ```lsof ``` and tune ```open_files_limit``` variable in ```my.cnf```.

(or maybe it exceeded maximum number of files that can be created in the mysql bin directory).

Comment: The value of `open_files_limit` was 4161. Now I increased it but still, the same error is showing, what is the fix?

Comment: what does ```lsof | grep mysql | wc -l```  say ??

Comment: I windows OS, is there any alternative if `lsof` of windows??

Comment: I dont know very much about windows but i have just done a little research on it and there is an external tool called sysinternal.   Checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle