# Unable to backup Mysql DB of size 30 GB | LAMP Stack

Tags: mysql, backup

We have an ubuntu server having mysql installed. There is one DB whose size is 30 GB in production. This DB contains tables, views, and store procedures. We use MySQL script to execute the backup on the server. It works fine with the DB size of around 2-5 GB but when we run the same script on a 30 GB DB server it time out, sometimes it doesn't contain the store procedure in the DB backup. We try various updates in the script but didn't work.

Below is some error we received while taking its backup.

[image]

Comment: Try some of the things in [getting Lost connection to mysql when using mysqldump even with max_allowed_packet parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53091734).

Comment: We tried this. Made changes to the parameter but still didn't work. ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away. The server connection is getting failed.

Comment: ERROR 1135 (HY000): Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug

Comment: You tried everything from that thread? And nothing worked? I would check the mysql server error log, maybe there is a problem with the table. Where did you get the memory error?